# Some parts of my code are not executed

Tags: c#

I'm trying to list all the duplicates in an array with the following code but i can't seem to get the correct results,i don't know whats seems to be the problem

```
for (int m = 0; m < malouda.Length; m++)
{
   for (int j = m + 1; j < malouda.Length; j++)
   {
   if (malouda[m] == malouda[j])
      {
      Console.WriteLine(malouda[j]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: maybe try to use HashSet instead

Comment: Think what will happen in array like this [1,1,1]. How many duplicates will it list? Is that the behavior you want?

Comment: What IS the problem? The code seems fine to me. I would write `m < malouda.Length - 1` but that doesn't change much.

Comment: I want it to list all the duplicates for example [1,1,1] i want it to list 1,1,1

Comment: What does *i can't seem to get the correct results* means? What results do you expect? What results do you have?

Comment: with the above loop you end up counting the same element more than once as you are not keeping track of the elements.

Comment: for example my array is " int[] malouda = new int[8] { 1, 5, 7, 1, 7 ,7,1,1}" but it prints the duplicates as next
5
next
7
next
1
next
7
next
7
next
1
next
1
next
Now the duplicates
1
1
1
7
7
1
1
7
1

Comment: The problem is, when there is only two match,you'll end up printing only one. ie if `malouda[m] == malouda[j]` is the only match for `malouda[m]`, you'll print only one of them and not the other.

Comment: So, you need more complex code, LINQ can help you, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use LINQ and you will get what you need:

```
var doubles = malouda.GroupBy(x => x)
   .Where( x => x.Count() > 1)
   .Select(x => new { Value = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(x => 
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < x.Count; j++)
          Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
   });
```

If you have this `[1, 2, 5, 2, 5]` you will get this:
2
2
5
5

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] malouda = { 1, 5, 7, 1, 7, 7, 1, 1 };

for (int m = 0; m < malouda.Length; m++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        if (malouda[m] == malouda[j])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} duplicate at index {1}", malouda[m], m);
            break; // exit inner loop if current item is duplicate
        }
    }
}
```

Output following duplicates:

```
1 duplicate at index 3
7 duplicate at index 4
7 duplicate at index 5
1 duplicate at index 6
1 duplicate at index 7
```

Comment: Thanx lazyberezovsky i got it!!!!now it works fine!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a set to keep track of "known" elements:

```
Set<int> s = new HashSet<int>();
for (int i in malouda)
{
    if (s.Contains(i))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    else
    {
        s.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with something like,

```
foreach (var match in malouda.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Any())
{
     foreach (var i in match)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(i);
     }
}
```